# Return data from Stored procedure and use in code behind without output or out Parameter

Tags: sql-server-2008, c#-4.0, stored-procedures

Is there is any other way to Get the data back in code behind from stored procedure without Out Parameter.

Example:-

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[MaxSalary]
@Msalary money OUTPUT
AS  
SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT @Msalary = max(salary)
    FROM tblSalary ;
GO
```

In code behind by using `SqlParameter` we can get the value easily like

```
SqlParameter outPutParameter = new SqlParameter();
outPutParameter.ParameterName = "@Msalary";
outPutParameter.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Money;
outPutParameter.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
cmd.Parameters.Add(outPutParameter);
double maxsal = Convert.ToDouble(outPutParameter.Value);
```

We can use Return as well but it will not return the data in code behind. now my question is that how we achieve the same result without using output parameter.

Hope you understand.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[MaxSalary]
 AS  
Declare @Msalary longint=0
SET NOCOUNT ON;
SELECT @Msalary = max(salary)
FROM tblSalary ;
return @Msalary 
GO
```

//getting return value

```
double maxsal = (double)mycommand.ExecuteScalar();
```

More details can be [found here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/37hwc7kt.aspx)